# sass-loader generates broken source maps

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, webpack-2, sass-loader

In my project I'm including one CSS file and one SCSS file:

```
require('./../vendor/glyphicons/glyphicons.css');
require('./../css/main.scss');
```

Source map for **CSS - works fine**:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        loader: ['css-loader?sourceMap']
    })
}
```

[image]

Source map for **SCSS - broken** (all rules point to same line, to parent element - `body`)

```
{
    test:   /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        loader: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
    })
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I see I'm not the only one having this [problem](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/272).

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        outputStyle: 'compressed', // This fixed the source maps
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

EDIT: I'm usinge `devtool: 'source-map'` in production and `devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map'` in development.

I don't fully understand the forces at play quite yet, but if you are looking to have your scss source maps point to the `@import` files with proper line numbers, this works.

The reason the line numbers are incorrect, in my case, I noticed sass complies something like

```
body {
   background: black;
}
```

to

```
body {
   background: black; }
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't too helpful, please try to explain your code.