# Unexpected term when using calc() with $variables

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm, postcss

I use [postcss-precss](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss) (simulates most of Sass features, but not math) combined with [postcss-cssnext](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext) (provides newest native CSS features, i.e. calc() which I'm missing in postcss-precss).

Normally I would combine Sass and calc() by interpolating `$vars` with `#{}`:

```
$size-width-search-btn: 40px;
.btn--search {
    width: calc(#{$size-width-search-btn} + 5); // is compiled to: width: calc(#{$size-width-search-btn} + 5); 
}
```

but this interpolation doesn't seem to be supported by postcss-precss - it's not proccessed at all. Good news, however, is that it works with no interpolation:

```
width: calc($size-width-search-btn + 5); // is compiled to: 45px
```

but then my IDE (PhpStorm 2016.3) doesn't recognize this syntax and I get this irritating highlight:

[image]

despite the fact this syntax is correct.

I cannot expect that cssnext would start to support interpolated vars (because it's an awful hack anyway), **I'd rather make WebStorm/PhpStorm recognize the simplified syntax with calc() and $vars**:

```
calc($var1 + $var2)
```

but how?

I cannot use postcss-sass, because this loader's source maps are [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784122/sass-loader-generates-broken-source-maps). I also don't want to change my .scss into .pcss, because JetBrain's [PostCSS plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8578) still doesn't support some of Sass features (like $variables, or inline comments).

Comment: So your problem is that PhpStorm doesn't support a certain, kind of hacky, syntax?

Comment: Well -- PhpStorm's PostCSS plugin page clearly indicates what modules it supports. The variables ticket (looks similar in terms of variables definition): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24368 (https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars). In mean time -- use CSS Custom properties perhaps (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/). P.S. All PostCSS tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=postcss

Comment: @Kyle No, please read carefully - this hacky syntax is normally supported, the simplified syntax (with no `$var` interpolation) is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @LazyOne - thanks, if I find no better alternative, I'm probably going to switch to native CSS vars, .pcss and PostCSS plugin.

Answer (score 24):

You can use variables inside like so:

```
calc(#{$a} + 10px)
```